# LIBGDX - adding Kidoz SDK crashes Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, ads

Whenever I am trying to add Kidoz SDK gradle dependency, the Android app will crash with these errors

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load shared library 'gdx' for target: Linux, 32-bit

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ... /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libgdx.so"
```

I am compiling on Ubuntu 14.04

project_root/build.gradle

```
    compile 'com.kidoz.sdk:KidozSDK:0.5.9'
```

If I remove this dependency everything runs fine. I can provide a demo project if helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer belongs to Fringale from LibGDX forums. He/She doesn't have a Stackoverflow account.

Fringale:

> I’m not sure why the error only appears after adding the Kidoz SDK,
>   but from the log it looks like the libgdx.so library for the desired
>   architecture (ARM64 I’d say, since it’s looking in
>   com.mobility.kpa-1/lib/arm64) is missing.
>
> The support for 64bit Android natives was added a few versions ago, so
>   maybe your Gradle files are not up-to-date:
>
> - Make sure the 'copyAndroidNatives' task in your android/build.gradle is correct by comparing it to the current one: [build.gradle](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-setup/src/com/badlogic/gdx/setup/resources/android/build.gradle#L28)
> - Check that you have all of those 5 lines in the 'project(":android")' section of the root build.gradle:

```
   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
   natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
```

> Just wanted to add that, the cause of your issue is that build.gradle
>   files are sometimes updated from one libGDX version to another, e.g.
>   to fix a bug or support a new feature like the Android 64bit natives.
>   The blog posts announcing new releases
>   (http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/) usually give specific
>   instructions when it happens. If you want to be on the safe side,
>   every few version you can also download the new setup app, generate an
>   empty project, and compare the resulting build.gradle files to the
>   ones in your project to see if some stuff has changed.